# Making a Jupyter notebook output cell fullscreen

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing a bit of choropleth map plotting in a Jupyter notebook (with Folium), and I was just wondering if there's any way of making an output cell fullscreen? It would just make the map a bit easier to view. If not, is there an easy way of modifying the maximum height of an output cell?

Comment: I think you best bet would be to use a custom jinja2 template and a function that will create the map and a link in the notebook to an html document created with the custom jinja2 template. The jinja2 template could have a 100% width and height map.

Comment: You could try to capture the output (plots, maps, table, number, ...) in python, convert it to HTML code, and write it to a new window using javascript. [This strategy works like a charm for Pandas dataframe tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554839/pop-out-expand-jupyter-cell-to-new-browser-window/40855214#40855214), but I am not sure about plotted maps...

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
    from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
    display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a Jupyter extension that let's a cell go fullscreen [here](https://github.com/scottlittle/expand-cell-fullscreen).  Installation instructions are on this Github page.

The heart of the extension is just making a selected element (a Jupyter cell) go fullscreen with this code:

```
function toggleFullscreen(elem) { //function to make element (cell) fullscreen on most browsers
  elem = elem || document.documentElement;
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
    !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Please see the Github page for the entirety of the code.

Answer (score 1):

**IPython.core.display is deprecated since IPython 7.14**

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

Comment: This answer seems to be building upon Toddneal Stallworth's answer, so it may be more accessible to other users if you edit that post instead.

Comment: I tried @Score_Under, but unfortunately, the suggestion queue is full ... :/
That is why I posted the update as an 'answer.'
I'm a StackOverflow newbie. If you have another idea, I will be pleased to try :)

Comment: That's okay, stack overflow is like that sometimes :/ I don't think there's a good solution to that

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Chrome, I figured out that just click

> **F12 -> F11 -> F12**

and then you get full screen mode.
Click F11 if you want to get out of the full screen mode.
I believe this method works because when you press F12, you access DevTool mode, where the F11 key is operational.

While this approach doesn't inherently extend the width of the cell, it does facilitate activating Chrome's full-screen mode. By adjusting the zoom level and selecting a suitable font size, you can create the illusion that the cell occupies the entire screen, enhancing its visual integration.

Answer (score -1):

Click F11, to view the Jupyter Notebook in Full Screen Mode. Click F11 once more, to come out of Full Screen Mode.