# How to display entire output of a code cell when the code is imported from a Python script?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am plotting some figures using matplotlib inside a notebook in JupyterLab. The code which is plotting these figures is imported from a .py file present in the same directory as of the notebook.

Assuming that figures are of appropriate size, how can I display them entirely i.e. where scrolling is not needed or disabled to display the output and I can get one-shot overview of the output given it is not populating the display beyond the screen size?

[image]

The issue is resolved if I copy the code from .py file and run it in the notebook directly:

[image]

I have tried Toddneal's answer from [Making a Jupyter notebook output cell fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576509/making-a-jupyter-notebook-output-cell-fullscreen), but scroll bar still exists in the output cell. I also referred to [How to avoid output into scrollable frames in jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641205/how-to-avoid-output-into-scrollable-frames-in-jupyter-notebook) and tried:

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.prototype._should_scroll = function(lines) {
    return false;
}
```

as the first code cell in the notebook, but gives out the error: `Javascript Error: Can't find variable: IPython`.

The output cell is already expanded, so the issue is with the height of the output cell. There are bunch of cells beyond the output cells (could that be possibly affecting the height of output cell?). The extension [autoscroll](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/autoscroll) might not work because it is a [Jupyter Notebook extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions#jupyterlab):

> Due to major differences between the Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab, the extensions in this repository will not work in JupyterLab.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the output and choosing "Disable Scrolling for Outputs"? Here outputs is plural because one cell can have several outputs.

Comment: @krassowski I didn't try that. Just did and it solved the problem! Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

As krassowki suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473594/how-to-display-entire-output-of-a-code-cell-when-the-code-is-imported-from-a-pyt#comment128029545_72473594), the scrolling is disabled by right-clicking on the output cell and choosing "Disable Scrolling for Outputs."